# How to fix build command issue?

Tags: npm, build, tailwind-css

I want to try Tailwind CSS but I meet an issue when I launch "npm run build". 
The console returns : tailwind command not found. However I successfully installed it.

I upgrade Node and npm.

this error message :

> OnePage@1.0.0 build /Users/ted/Documents/Dweb/HTML : CSS/Projets/OnePage
>   tailwind build src/css/tailwind.css -o dist/css/tailwind.css

```
sh: tailwind: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! OnePage@1.0.0 build: `tailwind build src/css/tailwind.css -o dist/css/tailwind.css`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the OnePage@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ted/.npm/_logs/2019-06-15T18_11_03_382Z-debug.log
iMac-de-Ted:OnePage ted$ sudo npm run start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ted/.npm/_logs/2019-06-15T18_13_18_897Z-debug.log


------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my bug log :

> info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run',
>   'build'  ]  info using npm@6.9.0
>
> 3 info using node@v12.4.0
>
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
>
> 5 info lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~prebuild: OnePage@1.0.0
>
> 6 info lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: OnePage@1.0.0
>
> 7 verbose lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>
> 8 verbose lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: PATH:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ted/Documents/Dweb/HTML
>   :
>   CSS/Projets/OnePage/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>
> 9 verbose lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: CWD:
>   /Users/ted/Documents/Dweb/HTML : CSS/Projets/OnePage
>
> 10 silly lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: Args: [ 10 silly lifecycle
>   '-c',
>
> 10 silly lifecycle   'tailwind build src/css/tailwind.css -o
>   dist/css/tailwind.css' 10 silly lifecycle ]
>
> 11 info lifecycle OnePage@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script 12
>   verbose stack Error: OnePage@1.0.0 build: `tailwind build
>   src/css/tailwind.css -o dist/css/tailwind.css`
>
> 12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
>
> 12 verbose stack  at ChildProcess.
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
>
> 12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
>
> 12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
>
> 12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
>
> 13 verbose pkgid OnePage@1.0.0
>
> 14 verbose cwd /Users/ted/Documents/Dweb/HTML : CSS/Projets/OnePage
>
> 15 verbose Darwin 18.6.0
>
> 16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run"
>   "build"
>
> 17 verbose node v12.4.0
>
> 18 verbose npm  v6.9.0
>
> 19 error file sh
>
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 21 error errno ENOENT
>
> 22 error syscall spawn
>
> 23 error OnePage@1.0.0 build: `tailwind build src/css/tailwind.css -o
>   dist/css/tailwind.css`
>
> 23 error spawn ENOENT
>
> 24 error Failed at the OnePage@1.0.0 build script.
>
> 24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional  logging output above. 25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Did you forget to run `npm install` in the directory? What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: I uninstall et reinstall all my packages and now it runs.